# Windows kernel error log

Tags: windows, kernel

There are many same events all my Hyper V servers environment. I haven't found any solution for this event. If you have the solution for this error can you help me?

```
>Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing/Admin
>Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-EventTracing
>Date:          4/28/2016 1:34:27 PM
>Event ID:      2
>Task Category: Session
>Level:         Error
>Keywords:      Session
>User:          NETWORK SERVICE
>Computer:      HYPERV01.prod.local
>Description:
>**Session "" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000022**
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an access denied error upon attempt to start network service. Your permissions are probably restricted.